# Is it possible to clone/duplicate a Sharepoint Request?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to create many Sharepoint Requests (New Items) that are almost exactly the same as other existing items with slight changes (new date, new title). I am looking to create a clone (or copy) of a current Sharepoint item to make a new request pre-populating the form with the information from the original item/request. This seems like really basic functionality.  For example, the request below is a weekly task, the only change is a new "Target Send" date. How can I create a duplicate of this type of request so that each time a whole new form does not have to be reentered? I am the using Office 365 version. Thanks for your suggestions.  [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set **Default Values** in the settings of each column.  Of course if your defaults change, then you will need to change the settings.

If you are truly creating items in bulk, you may want to look into a coded/scripted solution like [Pnp-PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps) where you can put [Add-PnPListItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnplistitem?view=sharepoint-ps) in a PowerShell loop.

Answer (score 0):

For modern view, you could try to customize the list form by Power apps to render the last item field value.

Sample demo:

```
First(SortByColumns([@TestList], "Created", Descending).'Project Name').'Project Name'
```

[image]